# Убрать часть меша из NavMesh

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть генерируемая карта, поделенная на чанки. Я использую NavMesh для поиска путей. Каждый чанк имеет два меша, один для рендера, другой для коллайдера. У того меша, что для коллайдера, вершины находящиеся на биоме гор я поднял далеко  вверх, для того чтобы по горам нельзя было ходить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос больше о оптимизации, как убрать эти куски навмеша над горами?

Пробовал делать NavMeshModifierVolume растянутый на всю сетку на той же высоте что и эти куски и ставил AreaType = NotWalkable.
Но при перезапекании они не убираются.
[Взято от сюда.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-it-possible-to-define-restricted-area-in-unity-navmesh.187984/)

Ещё пробовал куб тоже растянутый, и для него в меню навигации во вкладке Object ставил Navigation Static и NotWalkable.
Но это работает только если есть Mesh Renderer на кубе, с не пустым материалом, тогда приходится создавать прозрачный материал, выключать тени и тд. Костыль одним словом.

Есть ли какой то более нормальный способ убрать эти куски?

Ps: Сейчас второй способ по какой то причине тоже перестал работать... Не могу починить, как блин это работает???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с NavMeshModifierVolume заработал как надо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть некоторые моменты которые нужно учесть:

1. NavMeshModifierVolume может быть хоть на пустом объекте, коллайдеры или меши не влияют
2. Область из компонента должна покрывать навмеш с запасом чуть ниже и выше чем сам навмеш, иначе работать не будет
3. Ну и поставить NotWalkable